# How to prevent logins using Windows Authentication in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, sql-authentication

SQL Server supports creating logins using [SQL, Windows, certificates and asymmetric keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments). Is it possible to remove the option of creating logins with Windows authentication (and just allow SQL authentication for example)?

Comment: Perhaps you could try login triggers, but I guess they can always be worked around by a sysadm. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks Nick.McDermaid, that is the closest solution to what i am looking for. One stat puts more than 80% of all hacks as having internal connection/help. So preventing/reducing access to the db is important.

Answer (score 3):

Natively you cannot prevent using Windows Authentication in SQL Server.

> SQL Server supports two authentication modes, Windows authentication
>   mode and mixed mode.
>
> Windows authentication is the default, and is often referred to as
>   integrated security because this SQL Server security model is tightly
>   integrated with Windows. Specific Windows user and group accounts are
>   trusted to log in to SQL Server. Windows users who have already been
>   authenticated do not have to present additional credentials.
>
> Mixed mode supports authentication both by Windows and by SQL Server.
>   User name and password pairs are maintained within SQL Server.

Microsoft also recommends using windows authentication over SQL Server logins.

> We **recommend using Windows authentication wherever possible**. Windows
>   authentication uses a series of encrypted messages to authenticate
>   users in SQL Server. When SQL Server logins are used, SQL Server login
>   names and encrypted passwords are passed across the network, which
>   makes them less secure.

As commented by Nick you can programmatically restrict the creation of logins from Windows user account, trusted domain account, or Windows groups.

Reference: [Authentication in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server)

A similar question was also answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135026/sql-server-connecting-without-windows-authentication?rq=1) by [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white-reinstate-monica).